# How to iterate over a query result Flask-Mongoengine if the cursor doesn't support list slices

Tags: python, flask-mongoengine

I am making a todo list app and i want to reverse the list that the query returns because I want the most recent todo item on top the error I am getting is 
`IndexError: Cursor instances do not support slice steps`
this is my code:

```
def index():
    todos = Todo.objects.all()
    todos = todos[::-1]
    return render_template('index.html', todo=todos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a datetime field? If you are sorting by the _id, you will sort by the insertion time. This basically means that the comparison is not done on just the timestamp portion..  Assuming you have a date field then something like this would use order_by to sort the result set.

[order_by](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=order_by#ordering) takes a variable number of string arguments, which are the field names (as defined in your documents) optionally preceded by a "-" (to indicate a descending sort, i.e. highest first).

```
def index():
    todos = Todo.objects().order_by('-datetimeFieldOfYourTodoCreation')
    return render_template('index.html', todo=todos)
```

Comment: thank you! Also how would i set a primary key so i can access the id of each item?

Comment: thefieldyouwantasprimary = StringField(primary_key=True)